# Can't stop mysql too many connections

Tags: mysql, shell

running

```
mysqladmin shotdown
```

gives

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Too many connections'
```

Can't find a solution to reboot mysql

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Comment: @nathanC Might need to kill the process first, depending on how screwed it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try sending `killall -sigterm mysqld`. Mysql should capture the signal and gracefully shut down without needing to create a connection to the server. If you are running multiple parallel instances of mysqld, and only wish to shut down one, you'll have to figure out which instance you want to kill, either by `netstat -lnp` and pick the listening port associated, or `lsof -n` and locate the database storage path for the instance you wish to stop. Then using the discovered pid, `kill -sigterm <pid>`